# responseObject is not JSON but NSInLineData for AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

Following code is to submit images through an operationQueue. The requests are all fired one by one correctly, the server response contains the image file name which client needs to get hold of. The problem is that the reponseObject for the success/failure block is not expected parsed JSON but type of NSInLineData shown in debugger. Now I suspect the code to construct the operation from the NSMutableURLRequest caused the issue. Please help.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"      
            URLString:podURLString parameters:nil
            constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

            NSError *error;
            BOOL success =[formData appendPartWithFileURL:imgURL name:@"images" fileName:img.path 
               mimeType:@"image/jpg" error:nil];
            if (!success)
                    NSLog(@"appendPartWithFileURL error: %@", error);} error:nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
   NSLog(@"Image Success: %@", [responseObject description]);

   NSString *imagePath = [response objectForKey:@"imageFileName"];

   [self.delegate networkManager:self didSubmitDeliveryImageForImageID:imagePath];


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"Image Error: %@", error);
  NSLog(@"image error: %@", [operation.responseObject description]);

 NSString *imageFilePath = [operation.responseObject objectForKey:@"imageFileName"];
 [self.delegate networkManager:self didFailSubmitDeliveryImageForImageID:imageFilePath];

}];
[manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

Comment: Removing this line `manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];` worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

When you get the response as NSInLineData. It's good to go now. You can write below single line of code to get NSDictionary if it supports json format.

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObjec options:0 error:nil];
```

Comment: not happening in my case. what can be the other reasons ?

Comment: can you share API Call i'l check it.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line of code before your `AFHTTPRequestOperation` block

```
**operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];**
```

Comment: response content type from server is not  application/json.
its applciation/octet-stream so this is not working for me. what to do ?